# Como parar a execução de um código no nodemon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

Qd eu quero executar algo usando o **nodemon** eu digito no terminal `nodemon nomeDoArquivo.js`, blz, mas e qd eu quero parar a execução?

Pq qd é um codigo tp timer por exemplo, a execução não para, então eu preciso fechar o terminal e abrir de nv para encerrar... Existe algum comando para parar a execução atual sem tem q fechar o terminal?

Comment: ueh só `ctrl + c` já para!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você quiser parar qualquer programa em execução no terminal, você ultiliza `Ctrl + C`

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso é melhor não usar o nodemon usa apenas node script.js, o nodemon ele fica monitorando seus arquivos, quando você altera algum arquivo ele da reload na aplicação isso é útil quando você esta desenvolvendo a aplicação. Mas no seu caso onde você quer executar apenas um arquivo não tem necessidade de usar.

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser apenas que ele execute uma vez e não fique executando continuamente/observando alterações nos ficheiros e actualizando automaticamente on save, você deve rodar apenas o comando `node nomeDoArquivo.js`. Se ainda assim você preferir usar o `nodemon` basta utilizar o comando que você usou anteriormente `nodemon nomeDoArquivo.js` e quando quiser parar a execução basta combinar as teclas `Ctrl + C`